# Notebook HP Pavilion - 17-g050nl (ENERGY STAR) what video driver should I use?

Tags: boot, grub2, login, hp, gpu-driver

After issuing do-release-upgrade the Notebook HP Pavilion - 17-g050nl (ENERGY STAR) shows the verbose boot but does not show the login screen. The only way I have to get into the system is to: power down, power up, hit esc to get to the hp boot menu, hit enter to continue, hit esc to enter into the grub boot menu, select ubuntu recovery mode, open a root shell, edit the grub default and remove quiet spash or whatsoever and replace it with nomodeset, save , perform update grub, reboot. I guess Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS does not recognize the video card or video driver that should be used with this hardware. What Drivers should I use to stop using nomodeset? How can I fix it? the output of sudo lshw -C display

```
    *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Wani [Radeon R5/R6/R7 Graphics]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
       version: c5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:f0800000-f0ffffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:feb00000-feb3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445 / 530/535 / 620/625 Mobile]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 81
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f01fffff ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fe700000-fe73ffff memory:fe740000-fe75ffff
```

Answer (score 0):

Right after boot, where the login screen shoud be, CTRL+ALT+F3 should take you to a console login...
If you're able to do that, you can log in and you can permanently set it to boot directly to the console(tty) so you can work on it, `sudo systemctl default-target multi-user.target`.

`sudo init 5` or `startx` will temporarily take you back to the graphical desktop, when you want to test your fix without rebooting... `sudo init 3` will kill that graphical desktop attempt.

If you get it fixed `sudo systemctl default-target graphical.target` will permanently set it back to boot into the graphical desktop.

note: from past experience, if you're booting into graphics mode and this is a graphics problem you may want to login/console fast as possible after boot and `sudo init 3` before it gets to a more unusable state(freezes)

**FOR THE UPDATED QUESTION**

use the xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu driver...

`apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu`

Comment: That is what I wanted to do. But strange enough if I let it boot and press ctrl+alt+f3 I do not get the tty.

Comment: @Malkavian Use nomodeset on your grub options and boot into your system, then reinstall your graphics drivers...

Comment: once you get the drivers installed and working you may also want to install dkms, if you haven't already

Comment: it is a Notebook HP Pavilion - 17-g050nl (ENERGY STAR). I thought that the default driver would work. What Should I install?

Comment: You could just reinstall whatever drivers you originally had installed before upgrading... `lspci | grep -i vga` will tell you what kind of graphics device you have... `ubuntu-drivers devices` may also help

Comment: ubuntu-driver devices has a blank output

Comment: i did sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu, then removed nomodeset and updated grub. i still get a black screen. so i had to rollback to nomodeset to get a working system

Comment: try the nouvea drivers xserver-xorg-video-nouveau